# list even values of a tree in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

Write a program that returns the list of even numbers of a tree

I do this:

```
(define (list_pares arbol)
  (cond
    [(empty? arbol) 0]
    [(and (es-hoja? arbol) (even? (dato-tree arbol)))
     (list (dato-tree arbol))]
    [else 
     (cond
       [(even? (dato-tree arbol))
        (append (list (dato-tree arbol))
                (list_pares (left-tree arbol))
                (list_pares (right-tree arbol)))]
       [else
        (append
         (list_pares (left-tree arbol))
         (list_pares (right-tree arbol)))])]))
```

But when run:

```
(list_pares (list 2 empty (list 5 (list 4 empty empty) (list 9 (list 6 empty empty) empty))))
```

returns me this error:

```
append: last argument must be a list, but received 0
```

how could it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message comes from this:

```
 [(empty? arbol) 0]
```

So when the resursion where you append the result end with an 0 instead of an empty list you get this problem because `(append '(something) 0 '(something else))` is not allowed.

What should you really return if you are given an empty tree and should return a list of even values from it?

Comment: then it would be this  [(empty? arbol) empty ] Thanks :)